# ProgressDialog dismiss is not working

Tags: android

I have a `ProgressDialog` set up but i ca not dismiss it! it just keep loading the message and wont end. I think I am doing it right, set up the show message in `onPreExecute` and `dismiss` it into `onPostExecute` but some how it's just not working

heres my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//String[] imgUrls = {getString(R.string.uncc_main_thumb),getString(R.string.football_main_thumb,getString(R.string.ifest_main_thumb),getString(R.string.commencement_main_thumb))};
String[] imgUrls={"http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4113/4843614620_c541de5a5c_m.jpg",
                  "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7265/8151547298_85e60e7368_m.jpg",
                  "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8054/8414075899_e87a74407b_m.jpg",
                  "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8210/8277674769_7d1245dbf1_m.jpg"};
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv2 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    iv3 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    iv4 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    for (String imgUrl : imgUrls) {
        new DownLoadImages().execute(imgUrl);
    }
}

private class DownLoadImages extends
AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        String imgUrl = params[0];
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imgUrl);
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return image;
}

       @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // show the loading message while downloading the image

            ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading");
        }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

           if (result == null) {
               result = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
                       R.drawable.not_found)).getBitmap();
            }

           //ImageView imageViewToBeAdded = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
          // imageViewToBeAdded.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            //     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          // imageViewToBeAdded.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

           iv1.setImageBitmap(result);
           progressDialog.dismiss();

}
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating instance of ProgressDialog.

Replace

```
ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading");
```

With

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
```

Comment: @Samson really? How is it possible? You have 4 different ProgressDialog and you are just overriding the references at every iteration of your loop

Comment: do you have better suggestion? i meant isnt it what im supposed to do? like setting the pregress dialog in the preExcute method

Answer (score 0):

Use `progressDialog` instead of `ProgressDialog` to call `show` method of ProgressDialog as:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
```

issue occurring due to you are calling show method using `ProgressDialog` but trying to dismiss using `progressDialog` instance.

Comment: the correct question is why the app does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

In onPreExecute you use the className ProgressDialog.show, which is a static method, in onPostExecute you are actually using your object to stop it.

Use your object to start it in onPreExecute and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your dialog and save the reference:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading");
```